# A really very simple expression in Java that is evaluated in a way that it is difficult to follow

Tags: java

While developing a web application in JSF, I came across an expression which was evaluated in a way that I couldn't follow. Let's represent the same expression with a simple Java code.

```
final public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {            
        int x=5;
        int temp=10;

        temp=temp + 1 + x;
        System.out.println("temp = "+temp);

        int var=10;
        var=var++ + x;
        System.out.println("var = "+var);
    }
}
```

---

In the above simple code snippet, the first case is obvious and it displays the value **16** through the statement `System.out.println("temp = "+temp);`. There is no question at all about it but in the second case, I have represented the same thing using the shorthand operator **++** (var++) and that causes the value **15** to be displayed on the console instead of displaying **16**. How is this expression evaluated here?

---

Here, there is an obvious thing that should be mentioned. In the expression var++, 10 is first passed and that value (not 11) is used to evaluate the entire expression on the right of the assignment which is in this case **var++ + x** and then **var** is incremented by 1. Accordingly, the assignment to itself **(var)** can not be observed here.
Where was the incrementation lost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Post increment operator like x++ means first you use the value x then you increment and in our case

```
 var=var++ + x;
```

assignment takes precedence.
Try this

```
 var=++var + x;
```

and you should get the value of 16.

Answer (score 4):

`var++` evaluates to var, and then increments `var`. So your expression is in fact evaluated to `var + x`.

The sequence of actions is the following:

- evaluate var++ : 10
- increment var : var = 11
- add x to 10 : 15
- assign the result of the addition to var : var = 15

Anyone programming like this should be banned from development, IMHO.

Comment: Hear, hear. I wish the compiler would reject it.

Answer (score 2):

You assigned a value to `var`,so the auto increment is executed but overwritten.

Your code would be better written as:

```
int var = 10;
var += x + 1;
System.out.println("var = " + var);
```

Comment: Both the autoincrement and the assignment are performed, in that order. See the answer above yours.

Comment: @David Conrad: In cosmic osmo's answer, he auto increments var once before executing the statement in question.  You can't reference answers by "above" and "below" because the order of the answers changes.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I was referring to JB Nizet's answer. There was only one other answer when I made that comment. My mistake.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Java Language Specification

> The value of the postfix increment expression is the value of the variable *before* the new value is stored.

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.14.2

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior of the post-increment operator.  You can see what's going on more clearly by running the following:

```
int var = 10;
var = var++;
System.out.println("var = " + var);

var = 10;
var = var++ + var;
System.out.println("var = " + var);
```

This should produce the output:

```
10
21
```

The post-increment operator returns the current value of the variable in the current expression, then increments it, so the incremented value is only visible the next time that variable is used.

In your code, you overwrite the value of var before the incremented value is ever used (so the incrementation is "lost").  I imagine the byte code is something analogous to:

```
// r holds the intermediate value of the expression while it's calculated
int x = 5;
int var = 10;

int r = r + var;
var = var + 1;  // note var is not read after this point
r = r + x;
var = r;
```